# Unable to implement a scrollspy with Bootstrap 4. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement something as simple as a **scrollspy in Bootstrap 4** for my portfolio and it's driving me to despair. I've read the official documentation, I've done my research, and I can't get it to work. No error in console.

Added data-spy = "scroll" data-target = ". Navbar" data-offset = "50" to the body and the anchors of the navigation links are the same as the section ids.

It also added the popper, jquery and other scripts.

I have also tried implementing it with just JavaScript, without success.

I start to think that there is something else in my code that is interfering with this Bootstrap function, but I can't find it. If anyone can take a look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong, I appreciate it.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="I'm a developer and audiovisual producer. Here I show my evolution, my work and my passion.">
        <meta name="author" content="Pablo Herrero">
      
        <title>Pablo Herrero | Developer | pabloherrero.me</title>
        

    
        <!-- Bootstrap style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Custom styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/121886ca53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Touch icons -->
    
    </head>
    <body id="top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">
                <div id="h" class="align-self-center">H</div>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" 
                type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target="#navbarResponsive" 
                aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="navbarResponsive" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#works">Works</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="container d-flex">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <img src="img/pabloHerrero.jpg" alt="Pablo Herrero" id= "headerPhoto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Pablo Herrero</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <h2>lore ipsum</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </header>

        <!-- About -->
        <section id="about">
            <div class="container d-flex">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 align-self-center">
                        <h2>Hi! I'm a developer and audiovisual producer.</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 align-self-center">
                        <p>I learned to code in 2019 when I started my studies on development. I'm confortable using Java, SQL, HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4 and GIT, although I'm always digging deep and learning new things. I'm currently working on JDBC, Swing, Android Studio, JavaScript and Python, and will start soon with TypeScript, Node.js and Angular. Here you can take a look at my projects and drop me a line with the contact form if you wish.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Works -->
        <section id="works">
            <div class="container d-flex">

            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Contact -->
        <section id="contact">
            <div class="container d-flex">

            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row d-flex ">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 align-self-center">
                        <small id="copy">&copy; 2020 Pablo Herrero</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 align-self-center">
                        <div id="social">
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/pablohs1986" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://dev.to/pablohs1986" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-dev"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/149406/pablohs1986?tab=profile" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://github.com/pablohs1986" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/pabloherrero1986/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap js -->
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Popper.js -->
        <script src="node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Portfolio script -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fira_coderegular';
    src: url('fonts/firacode-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/firacode-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'fira_codebold';
    src: url('fonts/firacode-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/firacode-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'fira_codemedium';
    src: url('fonts/firacode-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/firacode-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* General */
body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'fira_coderegular';
    letter-spacing: normal;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
  
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Navbar */
#navbar {
    min-height: 56px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#navbar .navbar-toggler {
    color: #000000;
}

#navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#h {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'fira_codebold';
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    outline: none;
}

#navbar .nav-link {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'fira_codemedium';
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    outline: none;
}

#navbar .nav-link:hover {
    color: #bd93f9;
    outline: none;
}

#navbar .nav-link:active {
    color: #50fa7b;
    outline: none;
}

#navbar #h:hover {
    color: #bd93f9;
    outline: none;
}

#navbar #h:active {
    color: #50fa7b;
    outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #navbar .nav-link {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem 0.5rem;
        color:#000000;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}

/* Header */
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#header .col-lg-12 {
    text-align: center;
}

#header #headerPhoto {
    margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#header h1 {
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'fira_codebold';
    font-size: 58px;
    line-height: 3.3rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

#header h2 {
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'fira_codemedium';
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #header #headerPhoto {
        margin: 75px 0px 0px 0px;
        max-width: 35%;
    }

    #header h1 {
        margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-size: 64px;
        line-height: 3.3rem;
        letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
    }
}


/* About */
#about {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#about .container {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#about .row {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

#about .col-lg-12 {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;

}


#about h2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: 'fira_codemedium';
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

#about p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'fira_coderegular';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Recent works */

/* Contact */

/* Footer */
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

footer #social a{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000000;
}

footer #social i:hover{
    color: #bd93f9;
}

footer #social i:active {
    color: #50fa7b;
    outline: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    footer #copy {
        float: left;
    }
    
    footer #social a{
        font-size: 20px;
        float: right;
        padding: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 0rem;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be [working fine](https://www.codeply.com/p/1hcQLKYm19), but the correct CSS selector for showing the active nav-link is...

```
#navbar .nav-link.active {
    color: #50fa7b;
    outline: none;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/1hcQLKYm19

Also note, the sections need height (or a lot of content) to see the menu changing between each section.

Comment: Oh man!!! you're right, it was the selector for the active nav-link... a stupid newbie mistake... because I'm a newbie ahahahaha

You don't know how much I appreciate it, I wasn't seeing at all!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have just forgotten to include bootstrap script like

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

if you want to do it with pure js just add event listener for the scroll event

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        // your handler
        console.log(window.scrollY);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helping me. If you have checked my code, you will have seen that the Bootstrap .js script is in. On the other hand, the JavaScript alternative you put forward doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: ohh sorry, I was confused that you've registered some scripts in your head and I haven't look inside body scripts, and for js script you should run it after page loads, updated the post

Comment: Absolutely right, I escaped popped.js above. I edit it!